# Transfer data from Viewcontroller to UIview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to draw a graph in a UIView with

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0f, 0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, Value1, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

If I define Value1 Inside my UIView.m it works but:
Value1 should be transferred from another ViewController, where i type the Value into a Textfield.

How do I transfer Value 1 into my UIView?

(I could transfer the Value to another ViewController, but in the ViewController my drawRect method doesn't work)

Comment: where do i have to put
    myView->Value1 = someValue;
    [myView setNeedsDisplay];
because it says "no known class method for selector 'setNeedsDisplay'"

Comment: you put whenever the value1 is ready and your view added its parent view and it shouldnt give you that error. edit the question and add the code.

Comment: did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

YourViewClass.h

```
{
@public
    CGFloat Value1;
}
```

ViewController

```
myView->Value1 = someValue;
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: It would be more appropriate to add a property instead of adding a public ivar.